Sanitize user-provided style attribute
I am sanitizing user input HTML coming from TinyMCE with the Symfony HTML Sanitizer.
How do I restrict the values of the style attribute? The documentation mentions that I can create a custom attribute sanitizer, but surely this is an extremely common use case that does not require me to implement my own CSS parser?
I want to allow font-size and color (e.g. something like <span style="font-size:10px;color:#00ff00">little green</span>, and forbid all other CSS rules (e.g. background images).

You will need to implement your own attribute-value parser. Such a string with style attribute should be easy to parse. The AttributeSanitizerInterface seems to make it very easy.
